# How can I create a Twitter stream using Node.js and Websockets?

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth, websocket

A few months ago (August 2011) I successfully created a node.js websockets server which connected to Twitter's [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api) using basic HTTP user/password authentication.  To do this, I employed Andre Goncalves' [twitter-nodejs-websocket](https://github.com/andregoncalves/twitter-nodejs-websocket) library.

Since creating this working implementation, Twitter has eliminated access to the streaming API via basic HTTP auth, in favor of **OAuth**.  After this shift, I utilized Ciaran Jessup's [node-oauth](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth) library, which has successfully given me access to the Streaming API again (when I run the server I am successfully outputting the tweets via console.log(tweet) -- see below ).

The problem now is that my websockets server is no longer working.  When I run my server from the command line and hit the client web page from the browser, the websocket "onclose" event is immediately fired.

I've tried everything I can think of to get this working.  Any help would be very greatly appreciated!

**server.js**

```
var sys    = require('sys'),
    http   = require('http'),
    ws     = require("./vendor/ws"),
    base64 = require('./vendor/base64'),
    arrays = require('./vendor/arrays')

var OAuth = require('./oauth/oauth').OAuth;

var consumer_key        = '[...]'; //removed for obvious security reasons...
var consumer_secret     = '[...]';
var access_token        = '[...]';
var access_token_secret = '[...]';

oa = new OAuth("https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                "https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token", 
                consumer_key,
                consumer_secret,
                "1.0A",
                null,
                "HMAC-SHA1");

var request = oa.get("https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=google", access_token, access_token_secret );

// Response Parsing -------------------------------------------- //

var clients = [];
var message = "";

request.addListener('response', function (response) {

    response.setEncoding('utf8');

    response.addListener("data", function (chunk) {

        message += chunk;

        var newlineIndex = message.indexOf('\r');
        // response should not be sent until message includes '\r'.
        // Look at the section titled "Parsing Responses" in Twitter's documentation.
        if (newlineIndex !== -1) {
            var tweet = message.slice(0, newlineIndex);

            clients.forEach(function(client){
                // Send response to all connected clients
                client.write(tweet);
            });

            // this just tests if we are receiving tweets -- we are: terminal successfully outputs stream //
            var pt = JSON.parse(tweet);
            console.log('tweet: ' + pt.text);
        }
        message = message.slice(newlineIndex + 1);
    });

});
request.end();

// Websocket TCP server

ws.createServer(function(websocket){
  clients.push(websocket);
  websocket.addListener("connect", function(resource){
    // emitted after handshake
    sys.debug("connect: " + resource);
  }).addListener("close", function(){
    // emitted when server or client closes connection
    clients.remove(websocket);
    sys.debug("close");
  });
}).listen(8081);


// This basic http server works, so we know this port is open.
//
// var http = require('http');
// http.createServer(function (req, res) {
//   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
//   res.end('Hello World\n');
// }).listen(8081);
```

**client code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://ec2-67-202-6-10.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8081");
    ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
        console.log('tweet')
    };
    ws.onclose = function() {
        console.log("socket closed");
    };
    ws.onopen = function() {
        console.log("connected...");
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you updated the browser? The websocket spec is chaning rapidly. Anyway, I'd propose using [socket.io](http://socket.io/) because it will even still work with fallbacks if the browser is outdated or websockets got incompatible again or a crappy proxy is preventing websockets from working.

Comment: I'm considering using socket.io but I've had trouble figuring out how to implement it.  Perhaps it is just an issue with the WebSockets spec changing, but I'm hopeful that someone who has worked these or similar libraries can spot a problem with my implementation.  Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @Squirkle: Is the example on https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io#readme too hard for you to understand?

Comment: the socket.io installation instructions are a little sparse, in my opinion (they show you the one line npm install, but once this is installed, how, on the client side is http://myurl.com/socket.io/socket.io.js supposed to point to an actual script, as they suggest it will?), and I have trouble figuring out how to make socket.io deal with my node request object...

Comment: @Squirkle: Just call `io.listen` on your webserver, it will then automagically respond to requests for that script and accept websocket connections and all that stuff.

Comment: @Squirkle: `var io = require('socket.io').listen(someServerObject)`

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'll take a shot at implementing socket.io and I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: @Squirkle how did it go then?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this sample event stream (it uses server sent events) from a twitter stream:

https://github.com/chovy/nodejs-stream